# Sharepoint custom field type

Tags: sharepoint, custom-controls, field

I have created a custom field type which inherits directly from SPField but when I try to add the field to a list I get the following error:

One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)

I have looked at the log file and there is no helpful information as to what is causing the problem and I have attached the debugger to the process and it exits after the base constructor for the field type has been called.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong from this error? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you adding the field to the list from code?

Comment: This http://skypestatusfield.codeplex.com/ is a custom SharePoint field type developed by a friend of mine. Download the source code and compare with yours, maybe you've missed something.

Comment: Did you check the diagnostic logging settings in Central Administration? Maybe there's no useful information in logs because of event throttling settings.

Comment: Event throttling was set to verbose but there was still no useful info. I stripped it right back to bare bones and managed to get it working but it is not clear what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a general catch-all error for many issues with custom field types. If you suddenly start to get it again, you may wish to investigate the following issues in the fldtypes...xml to begin with:

1. Unrecognised ParentType
2. Changed field type name (all existing columns will have to be recreated)
3. Not deployed correctly due to debugger false-start (I hate this one)

There are many, many other possibilities; but this is a good thing to rule out at the start.